# numerical data conversion to feature vector

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, feature-extraction

I wanted to normalize numerical data into feature vector with this code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

def clearRegister():
    clear_register = []
    zero = 0
    for i in range(21):
        clear_register.append(0)
    return clear_register

def header():
    clear_register = []
    name = 'c'
    entry = 1
    for i in range(21):
        clear_register.append(name+str(entry))
        entry += 1
    return clear_register

def convert(filename):
    clear_dataset = []
    clear_dataset.append(header())
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            clear_register = clearRegister()
            clear_register[(int(row["blue1"])-1)] = 1
            clear_register[(int(row["blue2"])-1)] = 1
            clear_register[(int(row["blue3"])-1)] = 1
            clear_register[(int(row["red1"])+9)] = 1
            clear_register[(int(row["red2"])+9)] = 1
            clear_register[(int(row["red3"])+9)] = 1
```

here is my csvfile input :

```
row blue1 blue2 blue3 red1 red2 red3 lable
0 1 5 4 6 2 8 0
1 2 3 1 9 4 5 1
. . . . . . . .
3000 5 7 4 3 8 10 1
```

i expect output like this( c1-c10 for blue, c11 - c20 for red ) :

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20 lable
 1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0  0
 1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0  1
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .  .
 0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   0  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1  1
```

*c11 - c20 is 'red' representation of c1 - c10, and all of them is unique. If c1,c5,c10 have value of 1, then c11,c15,c20 can't have that.*

i tried to call it with :

```
df = convert("dataset.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df1)
```

and i got this result :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Is something wrong or lacking with the code ?

Comment: is there a posibility of blue1 = blue2 = blue3, and the same for red and what you will actually need is count? or will the answer always be binary

Comment: always binary. i forgot to mention that they're non repetitive (unique) for both, so if c1 have value of 1, c11 as representative of red c1 will not have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a pandas' solution as opposed to csv manipulation using `loc` to iteratively create new *c1-c20* columns. Below demonstrates with random data:

**Data** *(only for readers of question where OP uses actual csv instead)*

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 25)

np.random.seed(5005)
df = pd.DataFrame({'row': range(3000),
                   'blue1': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'blue2': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'blue3': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'red1': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'red2': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'red3': [np.random.randint(11) for _ in range(3000)],
                   'lable': [0,1]*1500})

print(df.head())
#    blue1  blue2  blue3  lable  red1  red2  red3  row
# 0      4      5      5      0    10     0     8    0
# 1      7      2      2      1     3     8     8    1
# 2      2      4      0      0     8     1     7    2
# 3      4      5      8      1     9     8     1    3
# 4      0      1      5      0     5     6     9    4
```

**Process**

```
for i in range(1,11):    
    df.loc[(df['blue1'] == i) | (df['blue2'] == i) | (df['blue3'] == i), 'c'+str(i)] = 1
    df.loc[(df['red1'] == i) | (df['red2'] == i) | (df['red3'] == i), 'c'+str(i+10)] = 1

# SELECT AND RE-ORDER COLUMNS, FILL IN NANs, CONVERT TO INT TYPE
df = df[['c'+str(i) for i in range(1,21)]+['lable']].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df.head())    
#    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14  c15  c16  c17  c18  c19  c20  lable
# 0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1      0
# 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0      1
# 2   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0      0
# 3   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0      1
# 4   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0      0
```

Comment: albeit the example given is 21x3000, my real dataset convertion contain 277 columns and 39500 rows, which make the execution run very slow...
either way, i truly appreciate your help. Thank you very much !